# How do I avoid calling a method that yields a block twice?

Tags: ruby

I am calling a third party API which yields a block and returns an array:

```
my.api.all arg: value do |ret|
  #block
end
```

I want to somehow call the method to get the size of the array:

```
array = my.api.all(arg: value)

if array.size > minValue
  #avoid calling all again, but how?
  my.api.all arg: value do |ret|
    #block
  end
end
```

Then I want to avoid calling the method again but have the code in the block that is yielded execute.

Is this in any way possible, or is there any way of avoiding calling the `all` method twice?

Comment: do you have access to the returned array while executing your block?

Comment: @fotanus I do not have access to the returned array in the block

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the block in a string and `eval` it later

```
str = ""

array = my.api.all arg: value do |ret|
    str = <<-eos
        #code e.g.
        puts "block executed with arg: #{ret}"
    eos
  end

if array.size > minValue
  eval str
end
```